# HTML5 input pattern search for quote

Tags: regex, html, validation, input

I need to test an input field (`<input type="text" />`) against this regex:

```
[^'"]+
```

This obviously is no easy task as I cannot use `"` inside the attribute. Using the quot entity does not seem to work as it gets interpreted literally by the regex engine.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I can't believe people actually suggested using a framework or library for regular expressions. Sheesh.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The HTML5 @pattern attribute regex is based on JavaScript regex, so you can use *hexadecimal notation* or *unicode notation* for that char as you would in JavaScript:

```
" = \x22 OR \u0022
' = \x27 OR \u0027
```

So that you can easily use

```
pattern="[^'\x22]+"
```

TADA! No JavaScript libraries involved! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Hexadecimal notation instead of `'` or `"`.

```
pattern="[^'\x22]+"
```

```html
<form action="#">
<input type="text" title="no quotes!" pattern="[^'\x22]+">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```