# I would like to add quotes to a regex expression in an HTML tag

Tags: html, regex

Here's some code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="Title" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\\\=\+\{\}\[\]\']{2,40}" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to add quotes to the allowed in the regex expression, however `\"` does not work and &quot does not work, either...

Comment: With that much included stuff, you could almost allow `.`.  Why not disallow characters instead?

Comment: I didn't think of that. How would I just disallow `.` and a couple others?

Comment: Disallow literal `.` --> `[^\.]`

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12620317/1378879

with " = \x22 OR \u0022
  with  ' = \x27 OR \u0027

Comment: Awesome, so I'd just replace quotes with `\x22`. @DanielHaley Awesome, too. Now I'll have to figure out which one to use. I can't remember all of the original reasons I chose to specifically allow, so I might stick with replacing it with `\x22`, since it's so simple and less modifying.

Comment: @StupidDev - You should add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted (and upvoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can just replace the quotes with `\x22`. Now I'll have to figure out which one to use (I can instead disallow instead of allow, or use `\x22` in place of the quotes). I can't remember all of the original reasons I chose to specifically allow, so I might stick with replacing it with `\x22`, since it's so simple and less modifying.