# how to process double quotes in Regex?

Tags: regex, html

i want to use Regex in div at HTML in order to replace a certain string, this string is like :
**age:7Refat"student"**   or it will be like **age:7Refat** , i'm using the following command that is ok with the *second* pattern:

```
$("#order_list").append($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("age:[0-9]+","g"),''));
```

but what if i want to use a general command for both patterns, the something is i don't know how to deal with the first pattern as it has double quotes"" , and i can't write:

```
$("#order_list").append($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("age:[0-9]+"[a-z]"","g"),''));
```

**or**

```
$("#order_list").append($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("price:[0-9]+[\"a-z\"]","g"),''));
```

Comment: This is first and foremost a basic javascript error. You need to escape the double quotes: "**\"**".

Comment: don't work, gives me a syntax error

Comment: You can also check the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343082/html5-input-pattern-search-for-quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That finally works with me :

```
$("#order_list").append(($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("age:[0-9]+","g"),'')).replace(new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]+","g"),'').replace(new RegExp("\"+","g"),''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Either escape the quotes like you did in your third example (but I think you put them in the wrong place):

```
new RegExp("price:[0-9]+\"[a-z]\"","g")
```

or (better) use a regex literal:

```
/price:[0-9]+"[a-z]"/g
```

Comment: this don't work, it gives me a syntax error as it reads the first quote as it the end of the exp

Comment: Have you wrapped the regex literal inside of quotes? Don't: the `/` character delimit the regex (for example: `/price:[0-9]+"[a-z]"/g` *not* `"/price:[0-9]+"[a-z]"/g"`, which *is* a syntax error).

Comment: i used the regexp you wrote ->>>  
new RegExp("price:[0-9]+\"[a-z]\"","g")

Comment: @Refaat - Sounds like you have an unmatched quote further upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$("#order_list").append($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("age:[0-9]+\"[a-z]\"","g"));
```

instead of this:-

```
$("#order_list").append($(this).text().replace(new RegExp("age:[0-9]+","g"),''));
```

Comment: this don't work, it gives me a syntax error as it reads the first quote as it the end of the exp