# How to set in pattern apostrophe?

Tags: html, input

I have the html page with the following input tag. I want to add an apostrophe `'` in this pattern.

```
<input pattern='^[,.’'()а-яА-ЯёЁ\\-0-9\"№?!;: iIіІўЎ]+$'  type='text'/>
```

But when I see it in browser DevTools (Google Chrome 45.0) I get the following input tag

```
<input pattern="^[,.’" ()а-яА-ЯёЁ\-0-9"№?!;:="" iiіІўЎ]+$'="" type="text"/>
```

So my pattern ends on my apostrophe and looks like **pattern="^[,.’"**.

I tried to set `\'`, but it didn't help. I really need some good advice how to do this. Thanks.

***EDIT***  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2sytf7u/)

Comment: To me it seems that using double quotes ( " ) should fix the problem

Comment: I got <input pattern="^[,.’" '()а-яА-ЯёЁ\-0-9"№?!;:="" iiіІўЎ]+$'="" type="text" />. And my pattern is small again

Comment: If you mean change pattern='...' to pattern="...", the apostrophe ' added well, but the pattern ends on my double quotes after 9

Comment: Your regex also seems to be broken I think, did you test it in some enviroment?

Comment: I didn't test it, but I the pattern without ' is working
`<input pattern='^[,.’()а-яА-ЯёЁ\\-0-9\"№?!;: iIіІўЎ]+$'  type='text'/>`

Comment: just escape the single quote with \'

Comment: I already wrote it in my question, sigle quote didn't help.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with a working example?

Comment: Please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343082/html5-input-pattern-search-for-quote)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343082/html5-input-pattern-search-for-quote/12620317#12620317). Use hexadecimal notation or unicode notation for that char as you would in JavaScript.