# Detect character in input using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to detect when an input has a double quote in it (") using ONLY CSS:  When invalid, i.e. has character in it, it should then show message.
Note:  The input value is dynamically placed in my editing interface.

```css
form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:valid {
  display: none;
  position: relative}

form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:valid ~ .requirements {
  display: none}
  
form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:invalid {
  display: block}
  
form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:invalid ~ .requirements {
  display: block}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="intdblquote">
   <input type="text" id="intdblquote" name="intdblquote" pattern="[^'\x22]+" placeholder= " " value="MyEntry""  required />
   <div class="requirements">Must not contain double quote.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [HTML5 input pattern search for quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343082/html5-input-pattern-search-for-quote) - Change your pattern to `pattern="[^'\x22]+"`

Comment: I changed pattern to suggested, but it's still not changing, based on what is in value.

Comment: @Santi  It's still not working properly, I added a quote to the end of my value, so you can see the new pattern is still not returning invalid.

Comment: You can't put double quotes inside an HTML attribute. It isn't valid. The `value` property ends at the second quote, and thinks that your extra `"` is just a mistake. [**It works fine.**](https://jsfiddle.net/cntkzkhz/)

Comment: @Santi Well, I understand about ending at second quote, but your example stripped out the value, which I need & the text will be dynamically put in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not getting it right, but I guess everything is almost allright. You might have messed up styles and escaping. This seems to work: the warning is shown when `"` symbol is typed in. If you want your default value to be `MyEntry"` enclose the attribute in `'`.

```css
form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:valid ~ .requirements {
  display: none;
}
  
form div#intdblquote > input[type="text"]:invalid ~ .requirements {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="intdblquote">
   <input type="text" id="intdblquote" name="intdblquote" pattern="[^\x22]+" placeholder="" value='MyEntry"' required/>
   <div class="requirements">Required. Must not contain double quote.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against. When the regexp is not satisfied, then `:invalid` pseudoclass takes over. Otherwise the `:valid` one comes into play.

Also notice that if nothing typed in `:invalid` pseudoclass comes into force since attribute `required` is present.