# Detect space/singlequote/double quote

Tags: regex

I am trying to detect either a space, single quote or double quote

Note:  this answer does not work for single quote (unless it's the very first character, I need to detect either in front of, inside of or after a string):  [HTML5 input pattern search for quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343082/html5-input-pattern-search-for-quote)

I have tried pattern="[^'\x20\x22]+"  and also pattern="[^\x20\x22\x27]+"

Could someone give me a regex that detects all of them please.

Comment: `[^a-z]` is not the start of the line or a-z, it means **don't** match a-z https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters

Comment: Do you want to match the string that doesn't contain a space/single quote or double-quote?

Comment: @Gurman  I want to match if the string DOES contain any of the mentioned characters, either before, inside of or after  - I think opposite of what you showed below

Comment: @parti Updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the strings that contain a space or `'` or `"`, use this regex:

`^(?=.*['\x20\x22]).+$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6ezBX/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?=.*['\x20\x22])` - positive lookahead to detect the presence of either a space or a `'` or a `"`
- `.+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character but a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: I see your demo works for single quote, but in my input box it doesn't match - I'm wondering if the app is ignoring it - can you think of another way to check for single quote that might get detected?

Comment: Your code does work, I also had to do an encoding fix in my app, so that it could see the single quote - All good now - thanks for your help.