# restrict special character in HTML input box using Angular 7

Tags: regex, angular, html

I need to restrict special character in html input box with Angular 7. Similarly I have some other requirement like to enter only number, letter etc.

Am new to Angular, any help will be appreciated.

I tried with some below code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="45" class="form-control" id="hno" [(ngModel)]="Address.number" pattern="^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';"<>?,./]*$">
```

Comment: Instead of dissallowing special characters, you should write expression for allowed characters.

Comment: @Saksham it's a good idea.

Comment: You can also create directive for same as you also have some other requirement also like enter only number or letter, So creating different directive for each requirement will be better idea

Answer (score 0):

Your `pattern` attribute should look like this:

`` pattern="[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';<>?,./\x22]*" ``

Firstly, you should NOT use `^` and `$` because you match every single character with this pattern.

Secondly, there is a problem with the `"` character. So for now I just removed it from the class, will look more into it.

**UPD**: Found a solution for a quote character [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620317/4732334). `\x22` works as `"` character.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qy5m07uh/

Comment: Sorry, its not working for me. I am able to enter special character into the input box

Comment: `pattern` attribute of HTML5 works when you try to submit the form.

Comment: Sometime ago, I made a directive, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field. If you use `[mask]="'^[A-Z|a-z|0-9]+$'"` can be work